# Unity - Apply two local rotations to object (trying to recreate the rotation of a controller joystick into a 3D mesh joystick)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I would like to recreate one on one the rotation of the real life controller joystick (i.e. 360 controller) into a 3D joystick mesh (that resembles the 360 controller one).

I thought about doing it by rotating the joystick in the X axis according to the magnitude of the input (mapping it to a min and max rotation in the X axis). And then figure the angle of the input and apply it to the Y axis of the 3D joystick.

This is the code I have, the joystick tilts properly in the X axis but the rotation in the Y axis doesn't work:

```
    public void SetStickRotation(Vector2 stickInput)
{
    float magnitude = stickInput.magnitude;

    // This function converts the magnitude to a range between the min and max rotation I want to apply to the 3D stick in the X axis
    float rotationX = Utils.ConvertRange(0.0f, 1.0f, m_StickRotationMinX, m_StickRotationMaxX, magnitude);
    
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(stickInput.x, stickInput.y);
    
    // I try to apply both rotations to the 3D model
    m_Stick.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationX, angle, 0.0f);
}
```

I am not sure why is not working or even if I am doing it the right way (i.e. perhaps there is a more optimal way to achieve it).

Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend rotating it by an amount determined by the magnitude around a single axis determined by the direction. This will avoid the joystick spinning around, which would be especially noticeable in cases of asymmetric joysticks such as pilots joysticks:

[image: pilot joystick example]

Explanation in comments:

```
public void SetStickRotation(Vector2 stickInput)
{
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    // CONSTANTS (consider making a field) //
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    float maxRotation = 35f; // can rotate 35 degrees from neutral position (up)

    ///////////
    // LOGIC //
    ///////////

    // Convert input to x/z plane
    Vector3 stickInput3 = new Vector3(stickInput.x, 0f, stickInput.y);

    // determine axis of rotation to produce that direction
    Vector3 axisOfRotation = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, stickInput3);

    // determine angle of rotation
    float angleOfRotation = maxRotation * Mathf.Min(1f, stickInput.magnitude);

    // apply that rotation to the joystick as a local rotation
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleOfRotation, axisOfRotation);
}
```

This will work for joysticks where:

1. the direction from its axle to its end is the local up direction,
2. it should have zero (identity) rotation on neutral input, and
3. `stickInput` with y=0 should rotate the knob around the stick's forward/back axis, and `stickInput` with x=0 should rotate the knob around the stick's left/right axis.

[image: joystick points in local up, joystick parent has up in direction of joystick neutral position]

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the problem, atan2 returns the angle in radiants, however the code assumes it is euler degrees, as soon as I did the conversion it worked well.
I put the code here if anyone is interested (not the change in the atan2 function):

```
public void SetStickRotation(Vector2 stickInput)
{
    float magnitude = stickInput.magnitude;

    // This function converts the magnitude to a range between the min and max rotation I want to apply to the 3D stick in the X axis
    float rotationX = Utils.ConvertRange(0.0f, 1.0f, m_StickRotationMinX, m_StickRotationMaxX, magnitude);
    
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    
    // Apply both rotations to the 3D model
    m_Stick.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationX, angle, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: One problem with doing it this way is that if the joystick is something where you can tell one side of the joystick from the other, the joystick will visibly turn when it's pushed around. For instance, it could have a texture that isn't the same on every side of the joystick, or have a shape that isn't fully rotationally symmetrical. To see what I'm talking about, make the joystick top a cube or something.

Comment: In the case of a very asymmetric joystick like a [pilot's joystick](https://i.imgur.com/q0ROkEt.jpg) it would look especially weird to see it spinning around.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation and reply Ruzihm! In my case it is a very generic mesh (i.e. pretty round) but I'll change the code just in case we make modifications to it in the future.